# Textview content is getting rendered in black color on android app

Tags: android, textview

In my android app I am overriding a textview draw() method and rendering the text in my app as follows. But on some devices I am seeing black textview instead of text. I set the back ground color to black and for-ground to white.

```
    @Override
    public void draw(@Nonnull Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, @Nonnull Paint paint) {
      canvas.drawText(text, positionX, positionY, paint);
    }
```

Upon inspecting the textView using android studio Layout inspector, I could see that text view has text inside.

```
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textVie1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/window_with_border"/>
```

[image]

Not quite sure what I am missing in and why it is coming as blank on certain devices and working as expected on others. Do I have to set any flag that is needed on some OS?

Comment: but you must set colors

Comment: Tried setting colors, no luck still the same black textview.

Comment: check paint font size

Comment: Its is same as what I am setting. In the Android Studio Layout inspector, I could see that textview contains text that I am setting (which is expected to render). But on the app its just black container.

Answer (score 0):

If you overriding a `TextView` then use in `xml` file full path to your class: package name and class name, for example:

```
<my.package.TextViewMy
    android:id="@+id/textVie1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/window_with_border"/>
```